# Javascript: Select all but one item from array with slice()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Let's say I have this array:

```
var myarray = [a, b, c, d, e];
```

I want to select every item in the array except c.

```
var myselection = myarray.slice(3,5);
```

This selects only d and e. I would have to do:

```
var myselection = myarray.slice(3,5) + myarray.slice(0,2);
```

This selects d, e, a and b, BUT the output is not usable as a selector, since myselection is now written without a comma in between e and a: "d,ea,b"

Do you know a way to solve this?
Maybe with negative numbers?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!
Lee

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use concat:

```
myarray.slice(3,5).concat(myarray.slice(0,2))
```

this evaluates to the array `[d,e,a,b]`.

Of course, if you know you just want to remove array element with index 2, then do:

```
myarray.splice(2,1)
```

`myarray` is now `[a,b,d,e]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `splice` instead:

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
arr.splice(2,1);
--> arr == ['a','b','d','e'];
```

if you don't want to mess with the original array you can `slice` to make a copy then `splice`

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var selector = arr.slice();
selector.splice(2,1);
--> selector == ['a','b','d','e'];
```

Comment: second part of this does not reutrns as you have posted,
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var selector = arr.slice().splice(2,1);
--> selector will reutrn ['c'];

Answer (score 1):

Use splice:

```
myArray.splice(key, 1);
```

it removes that unwanted row.

Comment: It's important to note that this mutates the original array.